# How to configure Apache Tika with apache Solr 1.4.1

Tags: solr, solrnet, apache-tika, solr-cell

I want to index a large number of pdf documents.

I have found a reference showing that it could be done using Apache Tika but unfortunately I cannot find any reference that describes I could configure Apache Tika in Solr 1.4.1.

Once configured I do have it configured, how can I send documents to Solr directly without using curl?

I am using solrnet for indexing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler)

Answer (score 3):

Support for [ExtractingRequestHandler in SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=79) is not yet complete. You can either finish implementing it, or work around it and craft your own HttpWebRequests.